# Write call/transaction is dropped in TransactionalEventListener

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-transactions

I am using spring-boot(1.4.1) with hibernate(5.0.1.Final). I noticed that when I try to write to the db from within `@TransactionalEventListener` handler the call is simply ignored. A read call works just fine. 
When I say ignore, I mean there is no write in the db and there are no logs. I even enabled log4jdbc and still no logs which mean no hibernate session was created. From this, I reckon, somewhere in spring-boot we identify that its a transaction event handler and ignore a write call.

Here is an example.

```
// This function is defined in a class marked with @Service
@TransactionalEventListener
open fun handleEnqueue(event: EnqueueEvent) {
    // some code to obtain encodeJobId
    this.uploadService.saveUploadEntity(uploadEntity, encodeJobId)
}

@Service
@Transactional
class UploadService {
    //.....code

    open fun saveUploadEntity(uploadEntity: UploadEntity, encodeJobId: String): UploadEntity {
        // some code
        return this.save(uploadEntity)
    }
}
```

Now if I force a new Transaction by annotating

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
saveUploadEntity
```

a new transaction with connection is made and everything works fine.

1. I dont like that there is complete silence in logs when this write is dropped (again reads succeed). Is there a known bug?
2. How to enable the handler to start a new transaction? If I do Propogation.Requires_new on my handleEnqueue event, it does not work.

Besides, enabling log4jdbc which successfully logs reads/writes I have following settings in spring.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem. This behavior is actually mentioned in the documentation of the TransactionSynchronization#afterCompletion(int) which is referred to by the TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT (which is the default TransactionPhase attribute of the @TransactionalEventListener):

> The transaction will have been committed or rolled back already, but the transactional resources might still be active and accessible. As a consequence, any data access code triggered at this point will still "participate" in the original transaction, allowing to perform some cleanup (with no commit following anymore!), unless it explicitly declares that it needs to run in a separate transaction. Hence: Use PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW for any transactional operation that is called from here.

Unfortunately this seems to leave no other option than to enforce a new transaction via Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW. The problem is that the transactionalEventListeners are implemented as transaction synchronizations and hence bound to the transaction. When the transaction is closed and its resources cleaned up, so are the listeners. There might be a way to use a customized EntityManager which stores events and then publishes them after its close() was called.

Note that you can use TransactionPhase.BEFORE_COMMIT on your @TransactionalEventListener which will take place before the commit of the transaction. This will write your changes to the database but you won't know whether the transaction you're listening on was actually committed or is about to be rolled back.